# RenderScript Variable types and Element types, simple example

Tags: variables, types, element, renderscript

I clearly see the need to deepen my knowledge in RenderScript memory allocation and data types (I'm still confused about the sheer number of data types and finding the correct corresponding types on either side - allocations and elements. (or when to refer the forEach to input, to output or to both, etc.) Therefore I will read and re-read the documentation, which is really not bad - but it needs some time to get the necessary "intuition" how to use it correctly. But for now, please help me with this basic one (and I will return later with hopefully less stupid questions...). I need a very simple kernel that takes an ARGB Color Bitmap and returns an integer Array of gray-values. My attempt was the following:

```
#pragma version(1)
#pragma rs java_package_name(com.example.xxxx)
#pragma rs_fp_relaxed

uint __attribute__((kernel)) grauInt(uchar4 in) {
uint gr= (uint) (0.2125*in.r + 0.7154*in.g + 0.0721*in.b);
return gr;  
}
```

and Java side:

```
  int[] data1 = new int[width*height];

  ScriptC_gray graysc;
  graysc=new ScriptC_gray(rs);

  Type.Builder TypeOut = new Type.Builder(rs, Element.U8(rs));
  TypeOut.setX(width).setY(height);
  Allocation outAlloc = Allocation.createTyped(rs, TypeOut.create());

  Allocation inAlloc = Allocation.createFromBitmap(rs, bmpfoto1,       
  Allocation.MipmapControl.MIPMAP_NONE, Allocation.USAGE_SCRIPT);
    graysc.forEach_grauInt(inAlloc, outAlloc);
    outAlloc.copyTo(data1);
```

This crashed with the message cannot locate symbol "convert_uint". What's wrong with this conversion? Is the code otherwise correct?

UPDATE: isn't that ridiculous? I don't get this "easy one" run, even after 2 hours trying. I still struggle with the different Element- and variable-types. Let's recap: Input is a Bitmap. Output is an int[] Array. So, why doesnt it work when I use U8 in the Java-side Out-allocation, createFromBitmap in the Java-side In-allocation, uchar4 as kernel Input and uint as the kernel Output (RSRuntimeException: Type mismatch with U32) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `convert_uint()` function. How about simple casting? Other than that, the code looks alright (assuming `width` and `height` have correct values).

UPDATE: I have just noticed that you allocate `Element.I32` (i.e. signed integer type), but return `uint` from the kernel. These should match. And in any case, unless you need more than 8-bit precision, you should be able to fit your result in U8.

UPDATE: If you are changing the output type, make sure you change it in all places, e.g. if the kernel returns an `uint`, the allocation should use `U32`. If the kernel returns a `char`, the allocation should use `I8`. And so on...

Comment: Using int gr= (int) (0.2125*in.r + 0.7154*in.g + 0.0721*in.b);results in the message Type mismatch with U32!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a Uint[] directly because the input Bitmap is actually 2-dimensional. Can you create the output Allocation with a proper width/height and try that? You should still be able to extract the values into a Java array when you are finished.

Comment: I know what you mean, Stephen, kernel will be passed trough a grid of same dimensions on input and Output-side. Therefore, I already included TypeOut.setX(width).setY(height); in the outAlloc Definition in Java. Or did I missunderstand you?

Comment: Whoops. I misread the initial code, because I was sure I had seen a 1D version of your code previously. The actual bug is that you picked "U8", when you should be using "U32" if you want uint.

Comment: It works, thank you both, Stephen and Miloslaw. I really think, it would be a great idea to add a table of corresponding data types in kernel and allocation into the documentation. I am sure that many others struggle with this too, when starting with RS. Thanks again!

Comment: Good idea. I can probably put together a reasonable table, and it would also be better to explicitly document the Element.U32... stuff, since not everyone can read that shorthand.